# Allow comments in Play JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am getting

> java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)

I have `/* ... */` comments in the file. I am using Play JSON, i.e.

```
play.api.libs.json.Json.parse(byteArray)
```

How do I make this work with comments? Where do I configure Play JSON to accept comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) do not allow comments like that, your JSON need to be an array, an object or combination of these. Other things will cause JSON parser error, in any language that I know...

If you need to add some comment, just create a string node in the object like:

```
{
   "_comment": "your comment here...",
   "someKey": "Some value"
}
```

Comment: Play with it if you want: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/wiki/JsonParser-Features (note, that I didn't test it ever) - I'll stay with opinion, that JSON with comments is wrong formatted, if you'll want to re-use the same JSON data in environment that haven't options for comments stripping you'll fail

Comment: Read why the comments __was removed__ from JSON: https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/RK8qyGVaGSr